# the path which it's longest is smallest in against other longest way in path fron 1 to n

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

We have a weighted graph (all the weights are positive).

What we want to do is we want to go from the first node to the last one (1 -> n) but when were are going from the first node to the last one, we have to choose the path which satisfies the property:

**longest way is smaller than the longest way in other paths**.

Comment: Is this the shortest path?

Comment: Huh? I'm unable to understand your title, and your property statement "longest way is smaller than the longest way in other paths" is either ambiguous or non-sensical. Please re-word.

Comment: @JimMischel  I mean that we have a graph, so we want to go from the first node to the last one. we have some path to reach the end but we want to choose a path which it's longest way is smaller than the longest way in another paths

Comment: @PhamTrung please read my last comment

Comment: you just repeat what you say in the question, what can be defined as longest way? better you should give an example. An good example should clear the doubt :)

Comment: Why not getting all the possible paths, then compare each longest way?